# Subversion revision specifiers inclusive or exclusive?

Tags: svn, version-control

I never seem to remember if Subversion revision specifiers (e.g. `-r 42:1337`) are inclusive or exclusive. Maybe it's different for the lower and the upper bound, who knows.

The Subversion [documentation on revision specifiers](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html) doesn't really mention it either.

So, which revisions are part of the range `42:1337`? Is 42 part of it and 1337? Or does it start with 43 and end with 1336?

Comment: It's a closed interval. I can't figure out a use case for an open one.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - but it (open) *partially* (half-open) exist in SVN

Answer (score 1):

Ranges are **inclusive most times** (and revision-specifiers page have good examples, demonstrating it)

```
$ svn diff -r BASE:HEAD foo.c
# compares the unmodified version of foo.c with the latest version of
# foo.c in the repository
```

But beware: shit happens! When you use range for [reverse-merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo), the right border is **not used**: `svn merge -r X:Y`  (X > Y) undo all revisions before X (including X) after Y (without Y)

Comment: It's definitively trickier than it looks at first sight. But merges involve *changes* between revisions, not revisions themselves, so I don't see them as an exception.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - nope, nein, ninguna!!! Revision **is** change (`merge -c`), even for direct range (:HEAD include changes, stored as HEAD)